# Set Web Deploy parameter values in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, webdeploy

I use MSBuild to build and deploy a web application.

```
 MSBuild.exe MySite.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:WebPublishMethod=MSDeploy /p:MSDeployServiceURL=mysite.example.com
```

My site connects to a SQL Server database.

```xml
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="dbconnection"
       connectionString ="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MySite;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I develop against a local database, but the connection string needs to be changed when the site is deployed to test or production servers.

I have declared a deployment parameter named `dbconnection` in a file named `parameters.xml`

```xml
<parameter name="dbconnection"
           defaultValue="Data Source={server};Initial Catalog={database};Integrated Security=SSPI;"
           tags="DBConnectionString"> 
  <parameterEntry type="XmlFile"
                  scope="\\Web.config$"
                  match="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='dbconnection']/@connectionString"/> 
</parameter>
```

I could easily create a parameterized web deploy package and deploy it with msdeploy.

```
msdeploy -verb:sync
         -source:package:MySite.zip
         -dest:iisApp="Site1/MySite"
         -setParam:name=dbconnection,value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MySiteTest;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

However, I'd really like to be able to do everything in MSBuild. What is the MSBuild equivalent of `-setParam`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameterization is not used when debugging locally.  So all you should have to do is set the defaultValue in your parameters.xml file to your desired connection string.

We create a SetParameters file for each environment (DEV, QA, MOCK, PROD) and call MSDeploy after MSBuild creates a WebDeploy package with the appropriate setParam file.  I don't believe there is way to use a custom SetParameters file when deploying directly from MSBuild.

Here is a post that further describes parameterization:

http://dotnetcatch.com/2014/09/08/parameterizationpreview-visual-studio-extension/

UPDATE:

Steven and I worked further outside of SO to understand his use cases better.  We confirmed again the MSDeployPublish target does not support setting parameter value overrides. To solve his use case I wrote some MSBuild script to provide the functionality he was looking for and wrote a blog post about it -

http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/04/27/setparameters-via-msbuild-commandline/

It basically works by passing a SetParameters file or list of key/value pairs via MSBuild Properties on the MSBuild.exe commandline.  The MSBuild script parses that out and overrides the parameters by setting the MsDeployDeclareParameters ItemGroup.

```
msdeploy.exe ... /p:MSDeployPublishSetParametersFile=SetParameters.Test.xml
msdeploy.exe ... /p:MSDeployPublishSetParameters=testSetting='changed_fromSetParam';IIS Web Application Name='Default Web Site/app13'
```

Comment: I'd be amazed if there is no way to do this. Visual Studio already supports `declareParam` in MSBuild via an ItemGroup: `MsDeployDeclareParameters`. I also came across `MsDeploySimpleSetParameters` but it doesn't seem to be used anywhere.

Comment: I agree this should be a built in option but I've never found a way.  In general, config transforms are the best way to edit the config if deploying directly from MSBuild.

Comment: The targets file contains some unused code that hints at better support for MSDeploy parameters (in `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets)`. It seems to me that they were in the process of adding `setParam` and `setParamFile` support in MSBuild, but then abandoned it.

Comment: Steven, I updated my answer based on our work.  If you agree this solves your question please mark it as the answer.  Thanks!  Nice working with you.

Comment: @chief7 please can you update the links that you provided?

Comment: Links updated.  Thanks for letting me know they were broke!